# Order by two columns with different priority - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, search

I want to be able to order users by two columns:

1. Number of followers they have
2. Number of the same following users that I am following - for similarity

Here's my query for now

```
SELECT COUNT(fSimilar.id) as similar_follow, COUNT(fCount.id) as followers_count, users.name FROM users 

  LEFT JOIN follows fSimilar ON fSimilar.user_id = users.id 
 AND fSimilar.following_id IN (
  SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = 1    // 1 is my user id     
 )
 LEFT JOIN follows fCount ON fCount.following_id = users.id  
WHERE users.name LIKE 'test%'
GROUP BY users.name 
ORDER BY followers_count * 0.3 + similar_follow * 0.7 DESC
```

This selects people that follow the same people as me and also considers their popularity (amount of followers). This is similar to Instagram search.

---

I prioritise `similar_follow` by 70% or `0.7`, and `followers_count` by 30%. However `followers_count * 0.3` doesn't provide ordering integrity. For example some users have 1 - 10 million followers, this causes `followers_count` to be too large and `similar_follow` becomes too small to have any impact on ordering.

I have considered doing `followers_count/500` where `500` is the average number of followers. However this still doesn't play well for ordering.

---

I need a way to equalise `followers_count` and `similar_follow`, so multiplication by percentages (`0.3` and `0.7`) makes a difference for both values.
I also looked at https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9#.wuz8j0f4w which describes **Wilson score interval** but I am not sure if this is the right solution in my case, as I deal with 2 values (I might be wrong).

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot find a `FROM ...` clause in your query.

Comment: `ORDER BY followers_count * 0.3 DESC, similar_follow * 0.7 DESC` actually equal to `ORDER BY followers_count DESC, similar_follow DESC` because coefficients in this case does not changes the order. Probably you want `ORDER BY followers_count * 0.3 + similar_follow * 0.7 DESC`?

Comment: @wildplasser sorry my bad

Comment: @Abelisto thank you - I haven't tested the code. But this isn't the issue I am facing...

Comment: @wildplasser please see update, my query is very slow despite having index on `username_id` column in `follows` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use LOG() when normalizing data that has a large range. Also, to reiterate @Abelisto, your attempt to weight each column doesn't work in your implementation. Adding the 2 together should work.

for example:

```
...
ORDER BY LOG(followers_count) * 0.3 + LOG(similar_follow) * 0.7 DESC
```

Comment: thanks, I will mark this as correct if no one else gives a better technique.

Comment: is it possible to add date sorting along with this sorting?

Answer (score 1):

What about multiplying by exponents (ie. `similar_follow ^ 3.0` and `followers_count ^ 1.5`)?
Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ForRealHomie, I implemented a query that works. I'm still opened for other 
suggestions :)

```
    SELECT 
users.id, users.name, 
fSimilar.count + fPopular.count as followCount 
FROM users

LEFT JOIN usernames ON usernames.user_id=users.id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  LOG(COUNT(user_id) + 1) * 0.7 as count, user_id 
FROM follows 
WHERE username_id IN (SELECT username_id FROM follows WHERE user_id=1)
GROUP BY user_id 
) fSimilar ON fSimilar.user_id = users.id 


LEFT JOIN (SELECT LOG(COUNT(username_id) + 1) * 0.3 as count, username_id 
FROM follows 
GROUP BY username_id 
) fPopular ON fPopular.username_id = usernames.id



  WHERE users.id IN (2, 3 ,4)


 ORDER BY followCount DESC
```

NB: `LOG(COUNT(...) + 1)`, `+ 1` is needed in order to accept `0` values that are generated by `COUNT`, because `LOG` doesn't accept `0` so `+ 1` fixes the issue :)